# Using a for loop to set values in jTextFields

Tags: java, arrays, swing, for-loop, jtextfield

```
        String[] words = str.split("\\+");
        jTextField43.setText(words[0]);
        jTextField44.setText(words[1]);
        jTextField45.setText(words[2]);
        jTextField46.setText(words[3]);
        jTextField47.setText(words[4]);
        jTextField48.setText(words[5]);
        jTextField49.setText(words[6]);
        jTextField50.setText(words[7]);
        jTextField51.setText(words[8]);
        jTextField52.setText(words[9]);
        jTextField53.setText(words[10]);
        jTextField54.setText(words[11]);
        jTextField55.setText(words[12]);
        jTextField56.setText(words[13]);
        jTextField57.setText(words[14]);
        jTextField58.setText(words[15]);
```

i want,

```
        for(int i=0;i<15;i++)
        {
              jTextField[i+43].setText(words[i]));
        }
```

How can I do?

Comment: use an array or Collection of JTextFields

Comment: Annnnd... what's wrong with the code you posted?

Comment: It seems to me that a `JList` would be a better component for displaying a collection of strings, than a collection of `JTextField` objects with one per string.  And for your fellow programmer's sake, please use more descriptive names for the fields.

Comment: How edit solved question? Now on hold. // English is Beginner :D // Google Translate: How can we change the status of pending cases resolved? @MadProgrammer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm just guessing here, but it looks as if all those `JTextFields` have been generated for you by an IDE using some graphical drag'n'drop editor(?)

If not, then the answer to your question is, *don't write your code that way*!

If you *did* use an IDE to create your UI, every time you drop a `JTextField` onto your Swing application the IDE is writing some code for you that generates a `JTextField` Object.

In the [NetBeans](https://netbeans.org/) IDE it does something like this:

```
// Variables declaration - do not modify                     
private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField1;
private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField2;
//etc...
// End of variables declaration
```

and elsewhere in a folded section of code marked "Generated Code" there'll be something like:

```
jTextField1 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
jTextField2 = new javax.swing.JTextField();

jTextField1.setText("jTextField1");
jTextField2.setText("jTextField2");

// plus some layout code that positions your controls...
```

The GUI isn't smart enough to know that all those `JTextFields` are somehow related and you would like to conveniently be able to loop through them. If you write the code yourself, instead of dragging and dropping the controls it's as easy as:

```
private JTextField[] jTextFields = new JTextField[35]; 

// initialise and set properties for all those JTextFields...
jTextFields[0] = new JTextField();
/// etc ...
```

Where 35 would be the number of JTextFields you need.

Alternatively, you could still use your IDE to create your GUI with drag'n'drop like you're used to doing and then put references to ALL those IDE generated controls into an array for easy iteration later:

```
private JTextField[] jTextFields = new JTextField[35];
jTextFields[0] = jTextField1;
jTextFields[1] = jTextField2;
// etc...
```

If you would rather use an ArrayList or similar container that is just as simple:

```
private List<JTextField> jTextFields = new ArrayList<>();
jTextFields.add( jTextField1 );
jTextFields.add( jTextField2 );
// etc...
```

In the case of Netbeans, the IDE defies all programming conventions and starts numbering controls at `1` instead of `0`, so watch out for off-by-one errors when you're putting `jTextField1` into `jTextFields[0]` and so on. Better still, give all your controls meaningful names!

I guess the bottom line is don't be afraid to write the code yourself rather than getting your IDE to generate it for you, and there's also no harm in putting your objects into containers if that is convenient to you.

Here's the relevant [FAQ entry for NetBeans](http://wiki.netbeans.org/FaqGuiControlArray) regarding arrays of GUI Controls that explains that you need to code it by hand.

If you're using another IDE, please refer to the relevant documentation to see if the IDE supports a way of creating Arrays or Collections of controls or whether or not you have to write the code yourself.

Comment: *"Better still, give all your controls meaningful names!"*  Great edit.  :)

Comment: @Andrew Thompson - That was inspired directly by your eminently sensible comment - I wasn't even going to bother with an answer to this at all, but it occurred to me that there's probably quite a few drag'n'drop programmers who may not even realise what code is being generated behind the scenes.